# increase NIC rx performance

Tags: linux, kernel, nic

I have an Intel 82598EB 10GBE NIC.

I need to receive traffic without packet loss.

Data rate is 4-5 Gbps, packet size is 1500-9600 bytes.

I had already configured smb and irq affinity.
I also tried to use packets socket ( PF_PACKET ).

None of this helped. Small losses is always present.

Now I am planning to compile kernel with disabling any configuration settings that increase the size of sk_buff and disabling IOMMU.

What are other ways to improve rx performance?

Answer (score 0):

During the day I was changing driver settings, and network subsystems settings. Found that only net.core.rmem_default has affect ( I am use UDP ).

Answer (score 0):

Rx or Tx Performance can be drop if your system is a numa node setup .
if your system has numa node , then while putting your 10G card in PCI_E slot , Check which CPU PCI-E Slot you are going to put then according to that assign irq to particular CPU core's and see if it helps .

Answer (score 0):

some nic default rx isn't set to max on default. the default and max value of rx/tx can be found using `ethtool -g <interface>`, and modified with command `ethtool -G <interface> rx value`.